# Use unique hosts for allocating Yarn resources in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We have 100+ nodes Yarn cluster, however pretty often when we submit Spark applications into it, 4 out of 5 executors are placed on the same physical node. Which is not great because our jobs are very network/cpu intensive.

Is it possible to configure Spark or Yarn to allocate resources on unique hosts instead?

[image: Spark Executors]

We are using **FairScheduler**: *yarn-site.xml*

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.user-as-default-queue</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.sizebasedweight</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.assignmultiple</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Just guessing...could it be that the node is the closest to the data you're accessing on HDFS? A (wild) idea would be to start your application with the maximum memory available for a container on a single node.

Comment: Nope, not the case. At the time of spark-submit yarn and spark has no idea what data will be used. 2nd option is not feasible, host machine has 124gb of memory and I really need only 4 ;)